# buck boost converter design using LM3759

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

I have requirement of DC output voltage in the range of 8V-30V and DC Output current to be max. 40Amps. I am using transformer 28-0-28, 7A rating transformer for the AC source. 
Can I change the Mosfet in LM3759 and inductors to a higher rating ones for achieving this output?

Comment: you can change anything you want , but never get the Pout >> Pin

Comment: you can change anything you want , but never get the Pout > Pin. Not >>. You even can't get  Pout = Pin.

Comment: Does this mean, if I buy a Buck Boost Converter online which has got MOSFET as switch on the board, I can do some modification to achieve my desired output? 
For example this one : https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/10-12-15-20A-150-250-300-400-1200W-Step-up-Step-down-Buck-Boost-DC-DC-Converter/282799323556?hash=item41d82739a4%3Am%3Am_K30WaLl7zDfO_YcMeqGRw&var=582112576618

Comment: No. Never. You have a 200-W transformer (28V*7A). Yet you want to have 30V@40A = 1200W output. This will never happen. Energy doesn't appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Sorry,  I did not mention that my output current range will be 6 Amps- 40 Amps max  depending on variation of Voltage range 8-30v.

Comment: 8V at 40A is still 320W, which is more than your transformer can deliver.

Comment: but what if I use my transformer not in Centre-tapped configuration rather in normal way. Can't I get 0-56 V? The transformer is 28V-0-28v.

Comment: No. This is still a 200-W transformer.

Answer (score 3):

There are few considerations:

1. Your transformer rating (28-0-28, 7A) usually means 28V full-bridge at 7A, meaning it is a 200-W rated transformer. No matter how do you connect the secondary  winding, it can't deliver more than 200 W.
2. Your output requirements of 8-30V at 40 A, even if the 40 A should be delivered only at 8-V set level, means 320 W output. The Nature has the Law of Energy Coservation, you can't get 320 W out of 200 W. To get 320 W output, you need a source that deliver more than 320 W, more likely as 400 W considering usual efficiency of DC-DC converters at 80%, plus-minus (320/0.8 = 400).
3. Even if you get a bigger (400+ W rated) power transformer, to get 40A out of a converter (where all variants are maxed at 20 A) would require substantial re-engineering. The high-side MOSFET must be beefier, the inductor must hold more current, the flyback diode (or low-side MOSFET) must be beefier, filter capacitors must likely have smaller ESR and higher ripple rating. And with twice of switching current there might be not enough power to drive these bigger transitors, and switching edges might be longer, so the efficiency migh suffer big. There is a reason why the LM3759-based family of boards all have the 20-A limit. So a rework of this design to 40 A will be quite challenging given the technical level of this question.